# Getting access to scss mixins and variables in global scss files from *.module.scss files in a React project

Tags: reactjs, sass, vite

Good afternoon. I am developing a project on React using ViteJS and SCSS preprocessor.

I need to configure the project in such a way that I can use scss modules near React component files. But I faced a problem that I can't get access from *.module.scss files to scss variables declared in global styles file.

And there are variables that I use all the time. For example, media query:

```scss
$tablet: 1050px;
$mobile: 767px;
$mobileSmall: 500px;
```

1. Search for a solution in ViteJS documentation and forums.
2. Searching for libraries found [sass-resources-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass-resources-loader), but it doesn't work with  the latest version of ViteJS